# Qt Installer Framework 2.0.1: Watermark only shows on the first page

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

I have made an installer for my application using Qt Installer Framework version 2.0.1 precompiled. I want the installer to have a watermark image on the left hand side throughout all the installer pages, but it only appears for the first.

Here is the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>ShaderNinja</Name>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Title>ShaderNinja</Title>
    <Publisher>Maxim Blinov</Publisher>
    <StartMenuDir>ShaderNinja</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@ApplicationsDir@/ShaderNinja</TargetDir>
    <InstallerApplicationIcon>sn</InstallerApplicationIcon>


    <Logo>snlogo.png</Logo>
    <WizardStyle>Modern</WizardStyle>
</Installer>
```

Note that I am using `<WizardStyle>Modern</WizardStyle>`.

Furthermore, when using `<WizardStyle>Mac</WizardStyle>`, the `<Background>` tag does nothing, even though it should as per the documentation.

However, if this is infact normal behaviour for a Watermark object, then how could I make it so it stays for all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at other installers, it turns out that this is how watermarks work.